# Cakephp findBy returns empty array

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following code:

```
print_r( $this->request->data['User'] ['username'] );
print_r( $this->User->findByRole($this->request->data['User']['username']) );
```

Now as you can see this is just to test it but when i try to run this i get the username correctly ( the first print_r) but the second print_r returns an empty array.

I know that there is a field called Role in my user database i also know that it is not empty. it should return employee.

So what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You're finding by role, not username - hence `findByRole`. i.e. You are searching the `role` column with the `username` value. You want to return the `role` field, not `findBy` it

Comment: @SmokeyPHP i want to find the field row where the username is equal to $this->request->data['User'] ['username']

Comment: @SmokeyPHP No i want to search the User model for the row "Role" where the username is equal to that of my array in this example the username is MyClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `findByUsername` and use the second parameter to specify the `fields`:

```
$this->User->findByUsername($this->request->data['User']['username'],array("User.role"));
```

Or the standard method:

```
$this->User->find("first",array(
    "fields" => array("User.role")
    ,"conditions" => array("User.username" => $this->request->data['User']['username'])
));
```

Comment: This gives me the following error: Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'User.' in 'field list'

SQL Query: SELECT DISTINCT `User`.``, `User`.`id` FROM `system_bloglic_com_test`.`users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`username` = 'MarcEmp' LIMIT 1

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Sorry, wrongly formatted the $fields array - see updated answer (I've also added a more verbose version if needed)